# Nothing rendering when using stat_density_2d(geom = "polygon")

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

For some reason `stat_density_2d()` does not seem to be working right for me when specifying `geom = "polygon"` and I am absolutely stumped. Here is my code...

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)
library(RANN2)
library(hexbin)
library(mapproj)

options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

raleigh_police <- rgdal::readOGR("https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/24c0b37fa9bb4e16ba8bcaa7e806c615_0.geojson", "OGRGeoJSON")

raleigh_police_sf <- raleigh_police %>%
  st_as_sf()

raleigh_police_sf %>%
    filter(crime_description == "Burglary/Residential") %>%
    st_coordinates() %>%
    as_tibble() %>%
    ggplot() +
    stat_density_2d(aes(X, Y, fill = stat(level)), geom = "polygon")
```

Here is my `sessionInfo()`...

```
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS  10.14.1

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] bindrcpp_0.2.2  mapproj_1.2.6   maps_3.3.0      hexbin_1.27.2   RANN2_0.1       forcats_0.3.0   stringr_1.3.1   dplyr_0.7.8    
 [9] purrr_0.2.5     readr_1.1.1     tidyr_0.8.2     tibble_1.4.2    ggplot2_3.1.0   tidyverse_1.2.1 sf_0.7-1       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.0       lubridate_1.7.4  lattice_0.20-38  class_7.3-14     utf8_1.1.4       assertthat_0.2.0 rprojroot_1.3-2 
 [8] digest_0.6.18    R6_2.3.0         cellranger_1.1.0 plyr_1.8.4       backports_1.1.2  evaluate_0.12    e1071_1.7-0     
[15] httr_1.3.1       blogdown_0.9     pillar_1.3.0     rlang_0.3.0.1    lazyeval_0.2.1   readxl_1.1.0     rstudioapi_0.8  
[22] rmarkdown_1.10   labeling_0.3     rgdal_1.3-6      munsell_0.5.0    broom_0.5.0      compiler_3.5.1   modelr_0.1.2    
[29] xfun_0.4         pkgconfig_2.0.2  htmltools_0.3.6  tidyselect_0.2.5 bookdown_0.7     codetools_0.2-15 fansi_0.4.0     
[36] crayon_1.3.4     withr_2.1.2      MASS_7.3-51.1    grid_3.5.1       nlme_3.1-137     spData_0.2.9.4   jsonlite_1.5    
[43] gtable_0.2.0     DBI_1.0.0        magrittr_1.5     units_0.6-1      scales_1.0.0     cli_1.0.1        stringi_1.2.4   
[50] sp_1.3-1         xml2_1.2.0       tools_3.5.1      glue_1.3.0       hms_0.4.2        yaml_2.2.0       colorspace_1.3-2
[57] classInt_0.2-3   rvest_0.3.2      knitr_1.20       bindr_0.1.1      haven_1.1.2
```

I just get a blank plot with nothing on it. Completely stumped. What am I doing wrong here?

## Update (2018-11-18)

It turns out that the primary issue here was `options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`. If you comment that out and run the original code, everything actually works fine. I found this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/782) which was the reason I tried that. Much more efficient code solutions are provided in the answers to this question and they also made sure not to use `options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`.

Comment: It works for me? I used `sf::read_sf` to read it in, but otherwise your code ran verbatim.

Comment: I really hope you're caching that file locally vs playing fast and loose with other people's bandwidth & CPU. Using `readOGR()` also results in warnings for null geometries. Jason: did you get that as well? And, I get a blank plot with warnings with the code provided.

Comment: @alistaire I tried `st_read()` and `read_sf()` on my R3.5.1/macOS 10.14.2 and get `Error in st_sf(x, ..., agr = agr, sf_column_name = sf_column_name) : no simple features geometry column present`. Can you post your working code as an answer along with `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: Jason: I could not even get the KML file they provide to work. But, you can grab the CSV and use it directly since it's just point-level data. (`longitude`/`latitude` vs `X`/`Y` for the plot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from downloading the file before reading and changing `readOGR` to `read_sf`, it works as-is for me save warnings for a couple `NA` points caused by empty geometries:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.6.1, GDAL 2.1.3, PROJ 4.9.3

path <- "~/Downloads/raleigh.geojson"
download.file(
    "https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/24c0b37fa9bb4e16ba8bcaa7e806c615_0.geojson",
    path,
    method = "curl"
)

raleigh_police <- sf::read_sf(path, "OGRGeoJSON")

raleigh_police %>%
    filter(crime_description == "Burglary/Residential") %>%
    st_coordinates() %>%
    as_tibble() %>%
    ggplot() +
    stat_density_2d(aes(X, Y, fill = stat(level)), geom = "polygon")
#> Warning: Removed 5 rows containing non-finite values (stat_density2d).
```

[image]

The empty rows:

```r
raleigh_police %>% 
    filter(crime_description == "Burglary/Residential", 
           st_is_empty(.))
#> Simple feature collection with 5 features and 21 fields (with 5 geometries empty)
#> geometry type:  POINT
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: NA ymin: NA xmax: NA ymax: NA
#> epsg (SRID):    4326
#> proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
#> # A tibble: 5 x 22
#>   OBJECTID GlobalID case_number crime_category crime_code crime_descripti…
#>      <int> <chr>    <chr>       <chr>          <chr>      <chr>           
#> 1   205318 8057315… P14076062   BURGLARY/RESI… 30B        Burglary/Reside…
#> 2   417488 70afb27… P15027702   BURGLARY/RESI… 30B        Burglary/Reside…
#> 3   424718 bdf69fa… P18029113   BURGLARY/RESI… 30B        Burglary/Reside…
#> 4   436550 711c05b… P18044139   BURGLARY/RESI… 30B        Burglary/Reside…
#> 5   442091 9d7a008… P18051764   BURGLARY/RESI… 30B        Burglary/Reside…
#> # … with 16 more variables: crime_type <chr>, reported_block_address <chr>,
#> #   city_of_incident <chr>, city <chr>, district <chr>, reported_date <dttm>,
#> #   reported_year <int>, reported_month <int>, reported_day <int>,
#> #   reported_hour <int>, reported_dayofwk <chr>, latitude <dbl>,
#> #   longitude <dbl>, agency <chr>, updated_date <dttm>, geometry <POINT [°]>

sessionInfo()
#> R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
#> Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
#> Running under: macOS  10.14.1
#> 
#> Matrix products: default
#> BLAS: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libRblas.0.dylib
#> LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib
#> 
#> locale:
#> [1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
#> 
#> attached base packages:
#> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
#> 
#> other attached packages:
#>  [1] sf_0.7-1           forcats_0.3.0      stringr_1.3.1     
#>  [4] dplyr_0.7.99.9000  purrr_0.2.5        readr_1.2.0       
#>  [7] tidyr_0.8.2        tibble_1.4.99.9005 ggplot2_3.1.0     
#> [10] tidyverse_1.2.1   
#> 
#> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#>  [1] tidyselect_0.2.5  haven_1.1.2       lattice_0.20-35  
#>  [4] colorspace_1.3-2  htmltools_0.3.6   yaml_2.2.0       
#>  [7] rlang_0.3.0.1     e1071_1.7-0       pillar_1.3.0.9001
#> [10] glue_1.3.0        withr_2.1.2       DBI_1.0.0        
#> [13] modelr_0.1.2      readxl_1.1.0      plyr_1.8.4       
#> [16] munsell_0.5.0     gtable_0.2.0      cellranger_1.1.0 
#> [19] rvest_0.3.2       evaluate_0.12     labeling_0.3     
#> [22] knitr_1.20        class_7.3-14      broom_0.5.0      
#> [25] Rcpp_0.12.19.3    scales_1.0.0      backports_1.1.2  
#> [28] classInt_0.2-3    jsonlite_1.5      hms_0.4.2.9001   
#> [31] digest_0.6.18     stringi_1.2.4     grid_3.5.1       
#> [34] rprojroot_1.3-2   cli_1.0.1         tools_3.5.1      
#> [37] magrittr_1.5      lazyeval_0.2.1    crayon_1.3.4     
#> [40] pkgconfig_2.0.2   MASS_7.3-51       xml2_1.2.0       
#> [43] spData_0.2.9.4    lubridate_1.7.4   assertthat_0.2.0 
#> [46] rmarkdown_1.10    httr_1.3.1        R6_2.3.0         
#> [49] units_0.6-1       nlme_3.1-137      compiler_3.5.1
```

Comment: I modified my code based on your answer to use `read_sf` instead of `read_OGR` and I still get the same blank plot result inside of my `RMarkdown` document.

I closed out my project and opened a fresh session, ran the modified code in a brand new `RMarkdown` document and got the desired output.

Is it possible that this has something to do with the project environment? I've never had this happen before.

Answer (score 2):

As noted, this is just point-level data and the CSV they provide can be a fine substitute:

```
library(tidyverse)

rp_csv_url <- "https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/24c0b37fa9bb4e16ba8bcaa7e806c615_0.csv"

httr::GET(
  url = rp_csv_url,
  httr::write_disk(basename(rp_csv_url)), # won't overwrite if it exists unless explicitly told to so you get caching for free
  httr::progress() # I suspect this is a big file so it's nice to see a progress bar
)

raleigh_police <- read_csv(basename(rp_csv_url))

mutate(
  raleigh_police, 
  longitude = as.numeric(longitude), # they come in wonky, still
  latitude = as.numeric(latitude) # they come in wonky, still
) -> raleigh_police

raleigh_police %>%
  filter(crime_description == "Burglary/Residential") %>% 
  ggplot() +
  stat_density_2d(
    aes(longitude, latitude, fill = stat(level)), 
    color = "#2b2b2b", size=0.125, geom = "polygon"
  ) +
  viridis::scale_fill_viridis(direction=-1, option="magma") +
  hrbrthemes::theme_ipsum_rc()
```

[image]

If you'd like to turn `level` into something more meaningful:

```
h <- c(MASS::bandwidth.nrd(rp_br$longitude), 
       MASS::bandwidth.nrd(rp_br$latitude))

dens <- MASS::kde2d(
  rp_br$longitude, rp_br$latitude, h = h, n = 100
)

breaks <- pretty(range(dens$z), 10)

zdf <- data.frame(expand.grid(x = dens$x, y = dens$y), z = as.vector(dens$z))

z <- tapply(zdf$z, zdf[c("x", "y")], identity)

cl <- grDevices::contourLines(
  x = sort(unique(dens$x)), y = sort(unique(dens$y)), z = dens$z,
  levels = breaks
)

sp::SpatialPolygons(
  lapply(1:length(cl), function(idx) {
    sp::Polygons(
      srl = list(sp::Polygon(
        matrix(c(cl[[idx]]$x, cl[[idx]]$y), nrow=length(cl[[idx]]$x), byrow=FALSE)
      )),
      ID = idx
    )
  })
) -> cont

sp::coordinates(rp_br) <- ~longitude+latitude
```

then:

```
data_frame(
  ct = sapply(sp::over(cont, sp::geometry(rp_br), returnList = TRUE), length),
  id = 1:length(ct),
  lvl = sapply(cl, function(x) x$level)
) %>% 
  count(lvl, wt=ct) %>% 
  mutate(
    pct = n/nrow(rp_br),
    pct_lab = sprintf("%s of the points fall within this level", scales::percent(pct))
  )
## # A tibble: 10 x 4
##      lvl     n     pct pct_lab                                   
##    <dbl> <int>   <dbl> <chr>                                     
##  1   10.  7302 0.927   92.7% of the points fall within this level
##  2   20.  6243 0.792   79.2% of the points fall within this level
##  3   30.  4786 0.607   60.7% of the points fall within this level
##  4   40.  3204 0.407   40.7% of the points fall within this level
##  5   50.  1945 0.247   24.7% of the points fall within this level
##  6   60.  1277 0.162   16.2% of the points fall within this level
##  7   70.   793 0.101   10.1% of the points fall within this level
##  8   80.   474 0.0601  6.0% of the points fall within this level 
##  9   90.   279 0.0354  3.5% of the points fall within this level 
## 10  100.    44 0.00558 0.6% of the points fall within this level
```

Comment: This is definitely a helpful alternative. Thank you for the suggestion! I also really appreciate your additional input on making level more meaningful. I was working through an example from James Cheshire and he started with an `sf` object so that was my point of reference. I think this is more straightforward.

Comment: The first bits are what ggplot2 does under the covers to compute the polygons/levels. I can change/augment the `Spatial…` bits with `sf` ones as well (some of are old and old habits die hard :-). I've been pondering making a PR into ggpot2 to add the %'s as a usable-computed stat.

Comment: Interestingly enough, it doesn't seem to matter how I change things up. I modified my code and I still get the same blank plot result inside of my RMarkdown document. I closed out my project and opened a fresh session, ran the modified code in a brand new RMarkdown document and got the desired output. Is it possible that this has something to do with something in the project environment? I've never had this happen before.

Comment: Aye. It's possible that there may have been a problem from anything from an issue with the RStudio graphics device (RStudio is far from a perfect product) all the way to — despite rigorous C-level tests — memory corruption issues with `sf`-ops/`readOGR`.

Comment: WOW - it was `options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` creating the problem. I commented that out, went back and ran my original code and everything worked. Referencing this GitHub Issue - https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/782

Comment: aye, that's a _super dangerous option_ to set globally